# Redirect to https increases site load time with Varnish

Tags: performance, https, varnish

I want to redirect every http request to https. I have modified my VCL file as:

```
import std;

sub vcl_recv {
  if (std.port(server.ip) != 443) {
    set req.http.location = "https://" + req.http.host + req.url;
    return(synth(301));
  }
}

sub vcl_synth {
   if (resp.status == 301 || resp.status == 302) {
       set resp.http.location = req.http.location;
       return (deliver);
   }
}
```

It worked but it increases my site loading to approximately 1s, whether the request is http or https.

Is there any other alternative approach i can use or improve load time performance?

Answer (score 2):

Varnish hardly adds latency to the request/response flow.

If the HTTPS resource that is redirected to is not cached, you will depend on the performance of your origin server. If the origin server is slow, the loading time will be slow.

### Browser timing breakdown

Please analyse the breakdown of the loading time for that resource in the "network" tab of your browser's inspector.

For that page that is loaded, you can click the "Timings" tab in Firefox to see the breakdown. Here's an example:

[image]

If the `Waiting` timer is high, this means the server is slow.
If the `Receiving` timer is high, this means the network is slow.

### Varnish timing breakdown

The `varnishlog` program allows you to inspect detailed transactions logs for Varnish.

The `varnishlog -g request -i ReqUrl -i Timestamp` will list the URL and loading times of every transaction.

Here's an example:

```
root@varnish:/etc/varnish# varnishlog -c -g request -i ReqUrl -i Timestamp
*   << Request  >> 163843
-   Timestamp      Start: 1645036124.028073 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1645036124.028073 0.000000 0.000000
-   ReqURL         /
-   Timestamp      Fetch: 1645036124.035310 0.007237 0.007237
-   Timestamp      Process: 1645036124.035362 0.007288 0.000051
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1645036124.035483 0.007409 0.000120
```

Timestamps are expressed in UNIX timestamp format. The first timer in every `Timestamp` log line is the total loading time since the start of the transaction. The second one is the loading time of the individual part.

In this example the total server-side loading time was `0.007409` seconds. The backend fetch was responsible for `0.007237` seconds of loading time.

Varnish itself wasted `0.007237` seconds on processing before the fetch, `0.000051` seconds of processing after the fetch and `0.000120` seconds for sending the response.

You can use this command to inspect server-side performance at your end. It also allows you to inspect whether or not Varnish is to blame for any incurred latency.

When there's no `Fetch` line it means you're dealing with a cache hit and no backend fetch was required.

### Conclusion

Combine server-side timing breakdown and client-side timing breakdown to form a conclusion on what causes the delay. Based on that information you can improve the component that is causing this delay.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to add `synthetic("")` to your `vcl_synth {}` to make sure that the redirects are sent with an empty body, but I agree that the code should not increase the response time by any significant amount.